# How to access method of the child component from parent in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to call child component from parent component in reactjs using refs.but it throws error saying showModal() is not a function when I tried to call.

//app.js

```
 class app extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
         super(props);

         this.POPUP = React.createRef();
      }
      showModal(){
            this.POPUP.showModal(true);
      }
      render() {
         return (
             <React.Fragment>
                <span><a onClick={() => this.showModal()}>Show</a></span>

                <POPUP onRef={ref => (this.POPUP = ref)}></POPUP>
             </React.Fragment >
       )
     }
 }
```

popup.js

```
 class POPUP extends Component {
   showModal(show) {
         console.log('showmodal');

     }
   render() {
          console.log(this.props.showModalPopup);
       <React.Fragment>
             <Modal

                 position="center">
                 <div>
                     //code
                 </div>
             </Modal>
       </React.Fragment>
       )
     }
 }
```

Is there any alternative in nextjs.please help

Comment: Where you've used `showpopup()` function ? It's not showing in the code

Comment: sorry wrong method its showModal()

Comment: In react, there is one way data binding, We can pass props (as methods and data) from parent to child. But not from child to parent. You can call parent's method(as a `this.props.callParentMethod(childData))` to pass child's data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call child method from parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949981/call-child-method-from-parent)

Comment: @MeetZaveri - can you please provide some code to understand

Comment: @Karthi Yurui's answer makes it a good example as to store main data in parent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#accessing-refs

First of all if you want to access that `POPUP` instance you should do

```
this.POPUP.current.showModal(true);
```

BTW Your `showModal` function needs to be bound to the child component if you intend to alter its state.

However, even this is doable - this is usually not the recommended way of doing `React`.

If you want the parent to decide if `showModalPopup` should be true, you probably should keep the state inside of your parent component:

```
 class App extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
         super(props);

         this.state = { showModalPopup: false };

         this.showModal = this.showModal.bind(this);
      }
      showModal(){
            this.setState({ showModalPopup: true });
      }
      render() {
         return (
             <React.Fragment>
                <span><a onClick={this.showModal}>Show</a></span>

                <POPUP show={this.state.showModalPopup}></POPUP>
             </React.Fragment >
       )
     }
 }
```

```
const POPUP = ({ show }) => (
    <Modal show={show} position="center">
      // your content.
    </Modal>
)
```