# Component with boolean value

Tags: reactjs

I have this component

```
const BoolComponent = ({ field1, Component1, Component2}) => {
  //...
  flag = functionGetBool(field1)
  return flag ? Component1 : Component2
}
```

When I use it, is there any way to get the flag variable in my component?
how can i get the answer's value?

```
<BoolComponent here i want to get the flag> </BoolComponent>
```

also here over:

```
<BoolComponent >
here i want to get the flag

 </BoolComponent>
```

Comment: It's totally unclear what/if there is a problem and what the question even is. Can you more clearly state what you are trying to do and what isn't working?

Comment: `<BoolComponent here i want to get the flag>` This is the place you send prop. So you can try `<BoolComponent flag={ functionGetBool(field1) }>` and in component, use it to return necessary component

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access method of the child component from parent in reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57955390/how-to-access-method-of-the-child-component-from-parent-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**State Lifting** sounds to be a great option in such cases. You can evaluate functionGetBool in parent component itself and pass it down as state in BoolComponent.

For reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

**Use Ref**

Secondly you can make BoolComponent a class component and make one function in it like

```
export function GetBool(){
 let flag = functionGetBool(field1)
return flag;
}
```

In your parent component you can use ref of BoolComponent and access the function GetBool() to know the value.

Comment: can you answer me with a example please